# Cross-Browser SVG rendering problems with circle and stroke-dasharray

Tags: svg, cross-browser, html-rendering, stroke-dasharray

my problem is explained quite simply. I've gotten a screenshot of the situation and snippet a jsFiddle code.

The problem I have, is clearly visible on the screenshot, the circular sections look perfectly in the Chrome browser, but in FireFox & Edge etc. the sections are slightly offset.

Prior to the current status, I had set the r / cx / cy properties to css, but that was not compatible either. I found out that you have to write them directly into the circle tag.

*Has anyone ever had the problem, I mean, but can anyone explain why it does not work as expected?*

**[EDIT]** THANKS @Sphinxxx for answer the basic question of y doesn't work that.

> **Is there a hack / workaround to solve the problem?**

---

Screenshot:

[image: Chrome | Firefox | Edge]
Browser on this Screen:
 1. Chrome
 2. FireFox
 3. Edge

**[UPDATE]** (In the current version of FireFox that issue is fixed)

- ***Now we have that problem only in the Edge browser***

[image]

Here to the code example:

```js
const duration = 1200
        Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('count')).forEach(el => {
            const target = parseInt(el.innerText)
            const step = (duration / target)
            const increment = step < 10 ? Math.round(10 / step) : 1
            let current = 0
            console.log(el.innerText + ': ' + step)
            el.innerText = current
            window.addEventListener('load', _ => {
                const timer = setInterval(_ => {
                    current += increment
                    if (current >= target) {
                        el.innerText = target
                        clearInterval(timer)
                    } else
                        el.innerText = current
                }, step)
            })
        })

        function getlength(number) {
            return number.toString().length;
        }
```

```css
svg.chart {
            width: 100px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background: yellowgreen;
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            animation: grow-up cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.18, 1) 2s;
            animation-delay: 0.3s;
        }

        .chart > circle {
            fill: none;
            stroke-width: 32;
        }

        .chart > circle.first {
            stroke: deeppink;
        }

        .chart > circle.second {
            stroke: mediumpurple;
        }

        .chart > circle.third {
            stroke: #fb3;
        }
  
        .chart > circle.fourth {
            stroke: #ce3b6a;
        }

        .legend-list li{
   width: 40%;
  }
        .legend-list span.glyphicon {
            color: yellowgreen;
        }

        .legend-list .first span.glyphicon {
            color: deeppink;
        }

        .legend-list .second span.glyphicon {
            color: mediumpurple;
        }

        .legend-list .third span.glyphicon {
            color: #fb3;
        }
        .legend-list .fourth span.glyphicon {
            color: #ce3b6a;
        }

        svg circle {
            animation: rotate-in cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.18, 1) .7s;
            animation-delay: 0.3s;
            transform-origin: 50% 50%
        }

        @keyframes rotate-in {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
                stroke-dashoffset: 30;
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
        }

        @keyframes grow-up {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
```

```html
<svg class="chart" viewBox="0 0 32 32"> 
 <!-- circle zero from 0 to 100 for filling yellowgreen --> <!-- 75 - 100 = 25 % -> realy 0 - 100 background color -->     
  <circle class='fourth' stroke-dasharray="75 100" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle> <!-- 60 - 75 = 15 % --> 
  <circle class='third' stroke-dasharray="60 100" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle> <!-- 40 - 60 = 20 % --> 
  <circle class='second' stroke-dasharray="40 100" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle> <!-- 30 - 40 = 10 % --> 
  <circle class='first' stroke-dasharray="30 100" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle> <!-- 0 - 30 = 30 % --> 
</svg>
```

Comment: If you want to draw an arc, use a path and draw an arc, don't try to bodge it with a circle and stroke-dasharray.

Comment: Using another tool is not the intended solution. I could also use chartjs etc. but would like to perform the rendering problem here after and can handle, but thanks

Comment: Robert's answer is the correct one. Trying to use a kludgy technique using thick arcs is a bad approach.  Hence the issues you are seeing.  Draw the sectors properly, as he suggests.

Comment: Okay, maybe that's the right approach you suggest. My problem with the approach is just that the build up of the SVG exorbitant will behave the way it is portrayed. With my setup, assigning the percentages was very easy. In your UseCase I have to first think of a formula to calculate the path depending on my values.
In my example, I could just use the value and he drew it.

Answer (score 1):

Both Edge and Firefox clearly do something wrong when drawing circles where the stroke meets itself in the circle center. Your example can be simplified to this:

```html
<svg class="chart" width="320" height="340" viewBox="1 0 32 34"> 
    <circle cx="16" cy="1"  r="8" stroke-width="15.5" stroke="green" stroke-dasharray="20 999" fill="none"></circle>
    <circle cx="16" cy="18" r="8" stroke-width="16"   stroke="blue"  stroke-dasharray="20 999" fill="none"></circle>
</svg>
```

The green circle has a stroke that's just a little bit too thin to reach the center, and looks like you would expect, with a tiny hole in the middle. The blue circle *should* perfectly close that gap, but somehow overshoots in a strange way:

[image]

The problem might be related to this: [Paths: Stroking and Offsetting](http://tavmjong.free.fr/blog/?p=1257), but doesn't quite look the same.

Comment: Here is the same problem without using circles -> https://codepen.io/badcat/pen/YVzmYY : in firefox & Edge rendert the grafic not like expected :/ But here works it correctly in all browser
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/stroke-dashoffset/ i have no plan about that XD its realy dirty XD